# Summation of a series with 2 different methods gives 2 different answers

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, geometric-progressions

The objective here is to find the value of $S$, where $S$ is given by,
$$S = 1-{1\over2}+{1\over3}-{1\over4}+...$$
I did this using two methods, but both the methods give different answers.

**Method 1:**

Let
$$S' = 1+{1\over2}+{1\over3}+{1\over4}+...$$
Now,

$1+{1\over2}+{1\over3}+{1\over4}+{1\over5}+{1\over6}+...$

$\;\;\;\;-1\;\;\;\;\;\;\;-{1\over2}\;\;\;\;\;\;\;-{1\over3}\;\;\;...$

$\frac{\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;}{}$

$1-{1\over2}+{1\over3}-{1\over4}+{1\over5}-{1\over6}+...$

So,
$$S = S'-S' = 0$$

**Method 2:**

Using the formula for infinite Geometric Progression, we can say
$$ 1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + ... = \frac{1}{1-x}$$
Integrating both sides with respect to $x$ from $0$ to $t$ we get,
$$[x+{x^2\over2}+{x^3\over3}+{x^4\over4}+...]^t_0 = [-ln(1-x)]^t_0$$
$$t+{t^2\over2}+{t^3\over3}+{t^4\over4}+... = -ln(1-t)$$
Putting $t = -1$,
$$-1+{1^2\over2}-{1^3\over3}+{1^4\over4}-... = -ln(2)$$
$$1-{1\over2}+{1\over3}-{1\over4}+... = ln(2)$$
So,
$$S=ln(2)$$
After some searching I found that the 2nd method gives the correct answer. But why is the 1st method wrong?

Comment: Why do you write $\infty$ at the end of each series?

Comment: I am actually new here. Sorry to do so. I will edit it.

Comment: Method 1 fails because $S'=\infty$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The series you denote by $S'$ is the divergent [harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_%28mathematics%29). You're implicitly using the theorem that the limit of the sum (or difference) of two sequences is the sum (or difference) of their limits. Since $S'$ has no limit, this theorem doesn't apply.

Answer (score 0):

There is no single correct value. This conditionally convergent series can be rearranged and summed to any value, see the example in
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem

Answer (score 0):

Furthermore, *Riemann's rearrangement theorem* asserts that for any conditionally , but not absolutely, convergent  series $u_n$, there is a rearrangement $u_{\sigma(n)}$ of its terms such that the re-arranged series converges to any prescribed number, or $+\infty$ or $-\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

I want to add a (minor?) point to the other answers.  You considered ∑*a*ₙ and ∑(-1)ⁿ*a*ₙ in the case *a*ₙ=*n*⁻¹.  What happens when one replaces this with *a*ₙ=*n*ˢ?

**Answer:** For any *s* *except* s=‒1 your argument “would work”.

(Quotes are needed since I assume *a particular* way of regularization of divergent series for *s*≥‒1.  However, I never saw any *other* way meaningfully used in the case of power-of-*n* series.)

Indeed, for *s*<‒1 your approach works due to the convergence of ∑*a*ₙ.  For *s>‒1*, both series may be regularized by Dirichlet method; the key observation is that Dirichlet regularization is *preserved by dilution* (which replaces *a*₁+*a*₂+… by 0+*a*₁+0+*a*₂+0+…).  (Note that the alternating series is also Chesaro/Abel/Borel summable — to the same answer as by Dirichlet.  The Chesaro summability is almost completely elementary.)

However, for s=‒1 the Dirichlet regularization gives ∞ (due to a pole of ζ(*z*) when *z*=1).  So in your calculation you get ∞‒∞, and you see that it is not necessarily 0.

Essentially, what you demonstrated is that when one gets ∞ with an “advanced” summation method, one should be *as careful as with the naive summation method*.